# Why does python mock.patch work differently when second patch argument is used vs return_value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock out the return value of a dependent method but the return value is different between using the `return_value` and adding an additional argument to the `mock.patch`. Please help me figure out why. I tried searching online but couldn't find an answer to this.

library/abc.py:

```
from tools.operating_system import os_name

class ABC(object):    
    def get_os_info(self):
        return os_name()
```

tools/operating_system.py:

```
import os

def os_name():
    return os.name
```

library/test_abc.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from library.abc import ABC

class TestMain(TestCase):
    # This works because the name method returns `test`
    def test_mocking_os_name(self):
        with mock.patch('tools.operating_system.os.name', 'test'):
            abc = ABC()
            res = abc.get_os_info()
            self.assertEqual(res, 'test')

    # The test fails because the name method returns `<MagicMock name='name' id='4515046400'>`
    def test_mocking_os_name(self):
        with mock.patch('tools.operating_system.os.name') as mock_name:
            mock_name.return_value = 'test'
            abc = ABC()
            res = abc.get_os_info()
            self.assertEqual(res, 'test')
```

Note: This example is somewhat contrived because I could mock the `os_name` method. That is not the main concern. I'm trying to learn python test mocking and I want to be able to mock `os.name`. Thanks! This is for Python 3.7.2 but I have the same problem with Python 2.7.15

Comment: look here --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch the second argument supplied to `patch` is not `return_value` so these two should not behave the same

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch): when you call this

```py
with mock.patch('tools.operating_system.os.name', 'test')
```

you're doing this:

```py
with mock.patch('tools.operating_system.os.name', NEW='test')
```

You're replacing `os.name` with the string `test`, so that works as you'd expect.

When you call this

```py
with mock.patch('tools.operating_system.os.name') as mock_name:
```

you're doing this:

```py
with mock.patch('tools.operating_system.os.name', NEW=DEFAULT) as mock_name:
```

You're leaving `NEW` as `NEW=DEFAULT` so `os.name` is set to `MagicMock` object (as the documentation says). Setting `mock_name.return_value='test'` does not work, because you're not calling the function `os.name()` anywhere in your code, and of course you should not be, because `os.name` is a string and not a function.

Like you said, in real code you would want to be patching `os_name` function instead of `os.name`:

```py
def test_patching_os_name(self):
    with mock.patch('library.abc.os_name') as mock_os_name:
        mock_os_name.return_value = 'test'
        abc = ABC()
        res = abc.get_os_info()
        self.assertEqual(res, 'test')
```

This test is not depending on the *internal implementation* of `os_name` function. If the correct behaviour of `ABC` class depended on `os_name` always returning `os.name` (which is what the tests are asserting), then the class could just as well use `os.name` itself and not depend on `tools.operating_system` at all.

A little personal preference for the end: I prefer injecting dependencies instead of patching whenever possible, see, for example, the article ["Every mock.patch() is a little smell"](http://mauveweb.co.uk/posts/2014/09/every-mock-patch-is-a-little-smell.html).